# How to create a form in Word that functions on screen and in print?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010, forms

I'm making a one-page form in Word that needs to be functional on screen with fillable fields and in print with lines.

What is the best way to do this? Right now I have a section that requires multiple lines, so I put a plain text content control in and drew a few lines. However, if that content control overflows to subsequent lines, the lines bump down, messing up the rest of the form down the line. So, I tried to set the lines to not move with text, but then I had to add carriage returns to space the next section out, and doing that cause a similar problem when the the content control overflowed to a new line.

So, is it possible to make this work? I think I can rig something with table cells, but I was hoping there'd be a more straightforward way to do it. Is it possible to do a section break where the new section starts at an absolute spot on the page, maybe?

Comment: You didn't specify how would you like the fillable fields to behave if the user enters in enough information to add extra lines to the document? If you want to restrict the number of characters for a field then you can use a legacy form field which allows you to set the maximum number of characters.

Comment: @Adam Well, that's the thing. I don't want to restrict the number of characters. I want it to be able to flow into multiple lines without any other formatting on the page being altered.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the content control to a textbox that is infront of text and set the textbox to resize shape with text this should work for you. Otherwise you might have to structure your template so that it looks good even if extra lines are added, i.e make sure paragraphs stick together, use non breaking spaces where needed etc

Answer (score 0):

If you choose "insert frame" under legacy forms in the developer tab > controls, and then add a legacy form field inside the frame, you can resize the frame to fit the space you want, and then typing will fill the frame without adding extra lines to the formatting of the document.